# Spring Boot: search by username returns null (Postgres)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to check a user's input against the database but am always getting  a `null` return (Spring Boot, Postgres). I'm thinking that my code is not actually touching the DB. Here is my controller, repo, service, and service impl. I don't know if I'm missing something or not:

**DSBInfoController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/DataSubmissionInfo")
public class DSBInfoController {

@Autowired
private DSBInfoService service;


private ProviderService pservice;

private ProviderRepo pr;




@Autowired
public Provider getProvider() {
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}


private Provider provider;


@RequestMapping(value ="/All", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void getAllInfo( @RequestBody String providername) {
    System.out.println("yo yo yo");
    System.out.println(  pservice.getByProviderName(providername));

}
```

**ProviderRepo.java**

```
public interface ProviderRepo extends CrudRepository<Provider, String> {


public Provider findByProvidername(String arg0);


}
```

**ProviderService.java**

```
ProviderService.java

import java.util.List;

import org.bellese.ehrbackend.beans.Provider;

public interface ProviderService {


public List<Provider> findAll();


public Provider getByProviderName(String arg0);


public <S extends Provider> List<S> save(Iterable<S> arg0);
}
```

providerServiceimpl.java

```
public class ProviderServiceImpl implements ProviderService {

@Autowired
private ProviderRepo repo;

@Override
public List<Provider> findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Provider getByProviderName(String providername) {

    return repo.findByProvidername(providername);
}

@Override
public <S extends Provider> List<S> save(Iterable<S> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

I'm still new to Spring Boot. I followed many tutorials with no avail. Please help.

Comment: It's Postgre**s** or PostgreSQL, never "Postgre". As for when asking a question, keep the code to the essential part and explain what's happening and what isn't. Don't just dump all code there and expect us to go through it for you.

Comment: From the db side, you can capture all queries (to check if the query is being executed), by setting `log_min_statement_duration=0` in the `postgresql.conf` and run `select pg_reload_conf()` as a Postgres superuser (eg. `postgres`), or you can change it for a specific user, eg. `alter role some_user set log_min_duration_statement=0` (again, as the superuser), and you can reset with `alter role some_user reset log_min_duration_statement`. You might want to set your `log_line_prefix` too, eg. `log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] (user=%u) (db=%d) (rhost=%h) [vxid:%v txid:%x] [%i] '` for better log output.

Comment: Please clarify the following: What data is in the database? How did you verify that? What value do you use for querying? What SQL gets generated and executed? What does that return when executed against the database with a generic DB tool?

Comment: You never set your field `ProviderService pservice`

Comment: can you post your Provider entity?